Screen height not expanding
I'm building a react native app with expo which is related to displaying tour dates. In my profile screen i am able to fetch and render tour dates directly and my profile screen height is expanding so that i can scroll and see date list but when i am displaying tour dates inside a tab profile height is fixed and not expanding at all. scrolling within tabs is working but i want to be able to scroll from profile screen and show all the date list at once for better viewing. I have tried using flatlist also i am having same issues. Can any one please help me with this. I believe there must be an issue with styling but i have tried updating every possible styles but still encountering the issue.
this is my profile.js code
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput, Linking, Platform, share, ActionSheetIOS } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { getFirebaseApp, getAuthInstance, getFirestoreInstance } from '../../utils/firebaseHelper';
import { collection, getDocs, getDoc, query, where, doc, updateDoc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { AuthContext } from '../../Context/AuthContext';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { TabView, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import {faMapMarkerAlt,faCalendarCheck,faRoute,faUser,faUsers, faAt, faInfoCircle,} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


const Profile = () => {

  const { userData, fetchUserData, isUserDataFetched } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const handleAddBioPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('TourManagerEditProfile');
  };
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const [displayedDates, setDisplayedDates] = useState([]);

  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState('all');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatePicker] = useState(false);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(null);
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0);

  // Hide the header
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);
    
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      if (!isUserDataFetched) {
        fetchUserData();
      }
    }, [isUserDataFetched, fetchUserData])
  );

  if (!userData) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }  

  // SocialLinks component
  const SocialLinks = ({ socialLinks, onAddSocialLinks }) => {
    const renderSocialIcon = (url, iconName, localIconSource) => {
      if (url) {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity key={url} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)}>
            {localIconSource ? (
              <Image source={localIconSource} style={styles.socialIcon} />
            ) : (
              <Ionicons name={iconName} size={28} color="#E2384D" style={styles.socialIcon} />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };

    if (!socialLinks) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onAddSocialLinks}>
          <Text style={styles.addSocialLinksText}>Add Social Links</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.socialLinksContainer}>
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.instagramUrl, 'logo-instagram')}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.linkedInUrl, 'logo-linkedin')}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.twitterUrl, 'logo-twitter')}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.facebookUrl, 'logo-facebook')}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.youtubeUrl, 'logo-youtube')}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.spotifyUrl, null, require('../../assets/images/spotifyicon.png'))}
        {renderSocialIcon(socialLinks.appleMusicUrl, null, require('../../assets/images/applemusicicon.png'))}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onAddSocialLinks}>
          <Ionicons name="add-circle-outline" size={28} color="#E2384D" style={styles.socialIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const handleShareProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const profileUrl = userData?.profileUrl; // Retrieve the profile URL from userData
  
      const message = `Check out my profile on OnTour! ${profileUrl}`;
      const url = profileUrl;
  
      const shareOptions = {
        message,
        url,
      };
  
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions(
          {
            url,
            message,
          },
          (error) => console.log('Error sharing profile:', error),
          (success, method) => {
            if (success) {
              console.log('Profile shared successfully');
            }
          }
        );
      } else {
        try {
          const result = await Share.share(shareOptions);
          if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
            console.log('Profile shared successfully');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error sharing profile:', error);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error sharing profile:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleEmailPress = () => {
    const emailAddress = userData?.email;
    const emailSubject = '';
    const emailBody = '';
  
    const emailUrl = `mailto:${emailAddress}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(emailSubject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(emailBody)}`;
    Linking.openURL(emailUrl);
  };

  const routes = [
    { key: 'mytours', title: 'My Tours' },
    { key: 'tourDates', title: 'Tour Dates' },
  ];

  const renderTabBar = (props) => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      indicatorStyle={styles.tabIndicator}
      style={styles.tabBar}
      labelStyle={styles.tabLabel}
      activeColor="#E2384D"
      inactiveColor="gray"
    />
  );

  const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'mytours':
        return (
          <View style={styles.tabContent}>
            {userData?.userTours && (
              <View style={styles.myToursContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.myToursTitle}>My Tours</Text>
                <View style={styles.toursContainer}>
                  {userData.userTours.map(renderTourCard)}
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        );
      case 'tourDates':
        return (
          <View style={styles.tabContent}>
            {userData?.allDates && (
  <View style={styles.tourDatesTabContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.tourDatesTabTitle}>Tour Dates</Text>
    <TourDates tourDates={userData.allDates} />
  </View>
)}
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  const TourDates = ({ tourDates }) => {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  
    const toggleShowMore = () => {
      setShowMore(!showMore);
    };
  
    const renderTourDate = (date) => {
      const venueName = date.venueName || '';
      const venueAddress = date.address || '';
  
      console.log('Date:', date);
      console.log('Venue Name:', venueName);
      console.log('Venue Address:', venueAddress);
  
      const isTourDate = date.tourId !== '';
  
      return (
        <View key={`${date.tourId}-${date.date}`} style={styles.tourDateContainer}>
          <View style={styles.tourDateHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.tourDateText}>{date.date}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.statusText, isTourDate ? styles.onTourStatus : styles.availableStatus]}>
              {isTourDate ? 'On Tour' : 'Available'}
            </Text>
          </View>
          {isTourDate && (
            <>
              <Text style={styles.tourNameText}>{date.tourName}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.actNameText}>{date.actName}</Text>
              {venueName ? <Text style={styles.venueNameText}>{venueName}</Text> : null}
              {venueAddress ? <Text style={styles.venueAddressText}>{venueAddress}</Text> : null}
            </>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    };
  
    const filteredDates = userData.allDates.filter((date) => {
      if (selectedFilter === 'onTour') {
        return date.tourId !== '';
      } else if (selectedFilter === 'available') {
        return date.tourId === '';
      } else if (selectedFilter === 'byDate') {
        const [day, month, year] = date.date.split('-');
        const tourDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
        return tourDate.toDateString() === selectedDate.toDateString();
      }
      return true;
    });
  
    const displayedDates = showMore ? filteredDates : filteredDates.slice(0, 30);

    return (
      <View style={styles.tourDatesContainer}>
        <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.filterButton, selectedFilter === 'all' && styles.selectedFilterButton]}
            onPress={() => setSelectedFilter('all')}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.filterButtonText, selectedFilter === 'all' && styles.selectedFilterButtonText]}>
              All
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.filterButton, selectedFilter === 'onTour' && styles.selectedFilterButton]}
            onPress={() => setSelectedFilter('onTour')}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.filterButtonText, selectedFilter === 'onTour' && styles.selectedFilterButtonText]}>
              On Tour
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.filterButton, selectedFilter === 'available' && styles.selectedFilterButton]}
            onPress={() => setSelectedFilter('available')}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.filterButtonText, selectedFilter === 'available' && styles.selectedFilterButtonText]}>
              Available
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.filterButton, selectedFilter === 'byDate' && styles.selectedFilterButton]}
            onPress={() => {
              setSelectedFilter('byDate');
              setShowDatePicker(true);
            }}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.filterButtonText, selectedFilter === 'byDate' && styles.selectedFilterButtonText]}>
              By Date
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {showDatePicker && (
          <DateTimePicker
            value={selectedDate}
            mode="date"
            display="default"
            onChange={(event, date) => {
              setShowDatePicker(false);
              if (date) {
                setSelectedDate(date);
              }
            }}
            style={styles.datePicker}
          />
        )}
        {displayedDates.map(renderTourDate)}
        {filteredDates.length > 30 && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleShowMore}>
            <Text style={styles.showMoreText}>{showMore ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderTourCard = (tour) => {
    const startDate = tour.dates[0]?.date;
    const endDate = tour.dates[tour.dates.length - 1]?.date;
    const showsCount = tour.dates.length;
  
    const tourCoverPhoto = tour.tourCoverPhotoUrl
      ? { uri: tour.tourCoverPhotoUrl }
      : require('../../assets/images/dafaulttourcoverphoto.png'); 
  
    return (
      <View key={tour.tourId} style={styles.tourCardContainer}>
        <Image source={tourCoverPhoto} style={styles.tourCoverPhoto} />
        <Text style={styles.tourName}>{tour.tourName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.actName}>{tour.actName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.tourDates}>
          {startDate} - {endDate}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.showsCount}>{showsCount} shows</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const handleToursCountPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('ToursCount');
  };

  const handleShowsCountPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('ShowsCount');
  };

  const handleUsersCountPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('UsersCount', { usersCount: userData?.usersCount || 0 });
  };

  const toggleExpanded = () => {
    setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
  };

  const handleAddSocialLinks = async () => {
    try {
      navigation.navigate('TourManagerEditProfile', { userId: userData.userId });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding social links:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleEditProfilePress = () => {
   
      navigation.navigate('TourManagerEditProfile');
    
  };

   const handleUpgradePress = () => {
    if (userData) {
      navigation.navigate('TourManagerMembershipOffer', { userId: userData.userId });
    }
  };

  const handleVerifyPress = () => {
    if (userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Pending') {
      navigation.navigate('TourManagerProfileVerification', {
        userId: userData?.userId,
        verificationStatus: userData?.idVerificationStatus,
      });
    } else {
      navigation.navigate('TourManagerProfileVerification', { userId: userData?.userId });
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
        {/* Cover photo with settings icon */}
        <View style={styles.coverPhotoContainer}>
          {/* Cover photo */}
          <Image
            source={userData?.coverPhotoUrl
              ? { uri: userData.coverPhotoUrl }
              : require('../../assets/images/defaultUserCoverPicture.png')
            }
            style={styles.coverPhoto}
          />
          {/* Settings icon */}
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settingsIcon} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TourManagerProfileSettings', { userData })}>
            <Ionicons name="settings" size={32} color='#E2384D' />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
  
        {/* User details */}
        <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
          {/* Profile photo */}
          <View style={styles.profilePhotoContainer}>
            <Image
              source={userData?.profilePhotoUrl
                ? { uri: userData.profilePhotoUrl }
                : require('../../assets/images/defaultUserProfilePicture.png')
              }
              style={styles.profilePhoto}
            />
          </View>

          {/* Stats */}
          <View style={styles.statsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.statItem}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleToursCountPress}>
                <Text style={styles.ToursCountNumber}>{userData?.toursCount || 0}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.ToursCountText}>Tours</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.statItem}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleShowsCountPress}>
                <Text style={styles.ShowsCountNumber}>{userData?.showsCount || 0}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.ShowsCountText}>Shows</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.statItem}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleUsersCountPress}>
                <Text style={styles.UsersCountNumber}>{userData?.usersCount || 0}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.UsersCountText}>Users</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
  
          {/* User info container */}
          <View style={styles.userInfoContainerWrapper}>        
            <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
             {/* User name */}
<View style={styles.userNameContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.userName}>{userData?.fullName}</Text>
  {userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Verified' ? (
  <Image
    source={require('../../assets/images/profileverifiedtick.png')}
    style={styles.verifiedTick}
  />
) : null}
</View>
  
              {/* User type */}
              <Text style={styles.userType}>{userData?.userType}</Text>
  
              {/* username */}
              <View style={styles.usernameContainer}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAt} size={16} color="gray" style={styles.usernameIcon} />
        <Text style={styles.username}>{userData?.userName}</Text>
      </View>
  
              {/* Location */}
              <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarkerAlt} size={16} color="red" style={styles.locationIcon} />
        <Text style={styles.location}>
          {userData?.city}, {userData?.state}, {userData?.country}
        </Text>
      </View>

              {/* Status */}
              <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
        
        {userData?.status === 'On Tour' ? (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRoute} size={16} color="red" style={styles.statusIcon} />
        ) : (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendarCheck} size={16} color="green" style={styles.statusIcon} />
        )}
        <Text style={[styles.statusText, userData?.status === 'On Tour' ? styles.onTourStatus : styles.availableStatus]}>
          {userData?.status}
        </Text>
      </View>

              {/* Expandable User Details */}
              {isExpanded && (
                <View style={styles.expandedContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.userDetailsContainer}>
                    {/* Bio */}
                    {userData?.bio ? (
        <Text style={styles.bio}>{userData.bio}</Text>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addBioButtonContainer} onPress={handleAddBioPress}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} size={16} color="red" style={styles.addBioIcon} />
          <Text style={styles.addBioButtonText}>Add Bio</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}

                    {/* Social Links */}
                    <SocialLinks socialLinks={userData?.socialLinks} onAddSocialLinks={handleAddSocialLinks} />

                    {/* Add more user details as needed */}
                  </View>

                  {/* Expand/Collapse Toggle */}
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expandToggle} onPress={toggleExpanded}>
                    <Text style={styles.expandToggleText}>Less</Text>
                    <Ionicons name="chevron-up" size={16} color="black" marginTop={2} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}

              {!isExpanded && (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expandToggle} onPress={toggleExpanded}>
                  <Text style={styles.expandToggleText}>More</Text>
                  <Ionicons name="chevron-down" size={16} color="black" marginTop={2} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
  
          {/* Edit button */}
          
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={handleEditProfilePress}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit Profile</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={handleShareProfile}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Share Profile</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {userData?.idVerificationStatus !== 'Verified' && (userData?.membershipTier === 'Pro' || userData?.membershipTier === 'Elite') ? (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={[
      styles.buttonStyle,
      styles.verifyButtonStyle,
      userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Pending' && styles.pendingButtonStyle,
    ]}
    onPress={handleVerifyPress}
  >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
      {userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Pending' ? 'Pending' : 'Verify Account'}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Verified' && userData?.membershipTier !== 'Elite' ? (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonStyle, styles.upgradeButtonStyle]} onPress={handleUpgradePress}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upgrade</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : userData?.idVerificationStatus === 'Verified' && userData?.membershipTier === 'Elite' ? (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.emailbuttonContainer, styles.emailButtonStyle]} onPress={handleEmailPress}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Email</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : null}
</View>
        </View>

        {/* Tours and Tour Dates */}
         <View style={styles.tabViewContainer}>
        <TabView
          navigationState={{ index: tabIndex, routes }}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          onIndexChange={setTabIndex}
          initialLayout={{ width: '100%' }}
          renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  coverPhotoContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  coverPhoto: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  settingsIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 40,
    right: 10,
    padding: 10,
    
  },
  detailsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: -60,
  },
  profilePhotoContainer: {
    borderRadius: 60,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
    width: 114,
    height: 114,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  profilePhoto: {
    width: 110,
    height: 110,
    
    borderRadius: 60,
  },
  userInfoContainerWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  userInfoContainer: {
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  userNameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
  userName: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  verifiedTick: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  verifyButtonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#E2384D',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginLeft: 80,
  },
  userType: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  userSubtype: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  location: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  statusContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  statusLabel: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  statusText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  onTourStatus: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  availableStatus: {
    color: 'green',
  },
  expandToggle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 0,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  expandToggleText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  userDetailsContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  addBioButtonContainer: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  addBioButtonText: {
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  socialLinksContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  socialIcon: {
    width: 28,
    height: 28,
    marginRight: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  addSocialLinksText: {
    color: '#E2384D',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  emailbuttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  upgradeButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#E2384D',
  },
  verifyButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#E2384D',
  },
  emailButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  pendingButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
  
  statsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: -50,
    width: '60%',
    marginLeft: 130,
  },
  statItem: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  ToursCountNumber: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  ToursCountText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  ShowsCountNumber: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  ShowsCountText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  UsersCountNumber: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  UsersCountText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  tourDateContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  tourDateHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  tourDateText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  
  tourNameText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 3,
  },
  actNameText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 3,
  },
  venueNameText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 3,
  },
  venueAddressText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  
  showMoreText: {
    color: '#E2384D',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  tourDatesTabContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tourDatesTabTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  filterContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  filterButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  selectedFilterButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#E2384D',
  },
  filterButtonText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'black',
  },
  selectedFilterButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  datePicker: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  myToursContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  myToursTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  toursContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  tourCardContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  tourCoverPhoto: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  tourName: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  actName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  tourDates: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  showsCount: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  tabViewContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  tabBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  tabIndicator: {
    backgroundColor: '#E2384D',
  },
  tabLabel: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  tabContent: {
    flex:1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    
  },
  userTypeContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  userTypeIcon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  usernameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  usernameIcon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  locationContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  locationIcon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  statusIcon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  addBioButtonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  addBioIcon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
});

export default Profile;

I have tried using flatlist also i am having same issues. Can any one please help me with this.

you could conditionally set minHeight on Profile to be larger when the length of the tour dates on display is a greater length than X.
